# All UIScrollView descendants in my app have stopped responding to scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uikit

I have no idea what I did, but I was implementing UIViewController Containment and all of a sudden the UIKit UIScrollView subclasses stopped responding to scrolling, even when I bypass all my custom application code. For example, this standard setup code...

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];

UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:vc.view.frame];
sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 3000);
[vc.view addSubview:sv];
```

In a brand new Xcode project the scrollView scrolls, but in my existing project, scrolling has no effect and scrollbars do not appear. The AppDelegate code in both projects are identical, my only #import is UIKit.

**In other words, all classes in my application that inherit from UIScrollView suddenly behave as if their scrollEnabled property is set to NO, and I can't change this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this was caused by lousy third party code that used `UIPanGestureRecognizers` without implementing `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`, thus overridding normal scroll behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the "scrolling enabled" property on the scrollview in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

```
  // define the area that is initially visible
  scrollViewCustom.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, 354, 500);

  // then define how much a user can scroll it
  [scrollViewCustom setContentSize:CGSizeMake(354, 960)];
```

In addition,clear the background color of scroll view to show the text.

```
   scrollViewCustom.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: This code is practically identical to the code I've presented in my example. I don't have a problem with the backgroundColor, the problem is with scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create like this.

```
scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]init]WithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0 ,320,480)];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: scrollEnabled is YES by default. And this problem affects every class that inherits from UIScrollView in my application (all UITableViews, UITextViews, etc).

Comment: Your scrollingView is working well then, What is your problem?

Comment: The problem is that all classes in my app that inherit from UIScrollView (UITableViews, UITextViews) have suddenly stopped responding to scrolling. ie. they all act as if scrollEnabled is NO, even though I have set it to YES.

Comment: tableView and textView are Controls not Classes. When Scroll on the tableView the scrollView will not scroll and scroll on textView scrollView will not Scroll, outside of these controls you are try to scroll will only scroll the scrollView.